# How to pass encripted data pass by url in angular 8

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular8, cryptojs

Tried to pass encripted data by url in angular 8 but not working because encripted data containing / so that url is not opening properly.So How to pass encripted data by url in angular 8.Please help anyone if know.

Can we encript the data without special chatacters.Is it possible?

Example: U2FsdGVkX18+ijuMYTf/b2jVWBRoAGWMJ+AnFlwodjE=   this data have / so url will not open. How to resolve this issue.

Encription like this:

```
     let encriptionData =  CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("test@gmail.com", 'secret key 123').toString();
```

I am passing encripted data like this

```
var url = "http://localhost:4200/content/" + encriptionData;
```

router.module.ts:

```
 { path : 'content/:id' , component : contentComponent },
```

content.component.ts:

```
 //url is http://localhost:4200/content/U2FsdGVkX18+ijuMYTf/b2jVWBRoAGWMJ+AnFlwodjE=

 this._Activatedroute.paramMap.subscribe(params => { 

    var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(params.get('id'), 'secret key 123');
    this.decryptedMailid = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);  
    console.log(this.decryptedMailid); 

  });
```

Comment: If possible, I'd recommend you url encode the encrypted data before changing the path

Comment: @ShamPooSham: How to encription the data without special characters?

Comment: You can use `encodeURIComponent` on the encrypted data

Comment: @ShamPooSham: Please..Can you edit my code? How to do it?

Comment: @ShamPooSham: If i use encodeURIComponent How to decode it for decription?

Comment: @ShamPooSham: Tried but not working..facing issue on decription.So please edit my code

Comment: I created an answer. I think this should work. If not, please tell me what result you get

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your encrypted string, and then decode it before decrypting it.

```
 let encryptedData =  encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("test@gmail.com", 'secret key 123').toString());
```

Now, instead of `http://localhost:4200/content/U2FsdGVkX18+ijuMYTf/b2jVWBRoAGWMJ+AnFlwodjE=`, your url will be `http://localhost:4200/content/U2FsdGVkX18%2BijuMYTf%2Fb2jVWBRoAGWMJ%2BAnFlwodjE%3D`

In content.component.ts, you do the following to reverse the operations:

```
this._Activatedroute.paramMap.subscribe(params => { 

    var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(params.get('id'), 'secret key 123');
    this.decryptedMailid = decodeURIComponent(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));  
    console.log(this.decryptedMailid); 

});
```